# Form not being added to bottom of table when table is apped to

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

When I add to table using jQuery

```
 $('#myTable > tbody:last').prepend('<tr><td>test</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
```

The form wrapped by div - `<div id="pager" class="pager">` always stays at same position even though the table has grown in size, shown in attached image, circled in red : 
I'm using this plugin : http://tablesorter.com/docs/index.html

[image]

I would like this form to be pushed to bottom of table when new items are added to the table. The items are added using jquery. I think I need to refresh the dom in order for the form to appear at bottom of table ?  Is there an alternative approach?

Here is the code running : http://jsfiddle.net/eUmDW/

Entire code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="http://tablesorter.com/__jquery.tablesorter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="http://tablesorter.com/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://tablesorter.com/themes/blue/style.css" type="text/css" media="print, projection, screen" />

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
                { 
                    $("#myTable").tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']}).tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")}); 
                    $('#myTable > tbody:last').prepend('<tr><td>test</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
                    $('#myTable > tbody:last').prepend('<tr><td>test</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
                    $('#myTable > tbody:last').prepend('<tr><td>test</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
                    $('#myTable > tbody:last').prepend('<tr><td>test</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
                    $('#myTable > tbody:last').prepend('<tr><td>test</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
                    $('#myTable > tbody:last').prepend('<tr><td>test</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
                } 
    });

   </script>

</head>


<body>

<table id="myTable" cellspacing="1" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Major</th>
            <th>Sex</th>
            <th>English</th>
            <th>Japanese</th>
            <th>Calculus</th>
            <th>Geometry</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Student01</td>
            <td>Languages</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>80</td>
            <td>70</td>
            <td>75</td>
            <td>80</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>AStudent01</td>
            <td>Languages</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>80</td>
            <td>70</td>
            <td>75</td>
            <td>80</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<div id="pager" class="pager">
    <form>
        <input type="text" class="pagedisplay"/>
        <select class="pagesize">
            <option selected="selected"  value="10">10</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option  value="40">40</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Guess your page first executes tablesorter js, setting the pager, and later adds the test rows. Just a wild guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your widget is adding `style="position: absolute; top: 72px;"` to your #pager div for some reason.

Quick work-around setting the css top back to auto will fix it

```
  $("#pager").css('top','auto');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eUmDW/2/

Comment: Thanks, I don't think this will work for me as the table will be appended to using jquery, since the table is being appended to dynamically the dom is not updated (when I view source) with the test values added by jquery. So the form is added to end of static content, not of dynamic (jquery) content.

Comment: Sure it will work for you. The `top: 72px` is only set when you first initalise your widget, once you reset it to auto it will stay that way and move up/down as expected when you add or remove rows.

Comment: btw; 'View Source' does *not* show the DOM. It shows the original source as received from the server.

Comment: above code is a snippet of much larger code base, it does work but when I try to sort the rows, the table returns to its original state for some reason, ill open a new question. thanks